# Reload a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a view, when it starts, the array of objects is read from memory and the Table View is completed with the objects. When I go to another view and write another objects to file and get back to the first view, the objects are loaded into the array from file as it should but the doesn't reload somehow... `[myTableView reloadData]` doesn't work, neither does `setNeedsDisplay`.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    contactsToLayNow=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fPath()];

    NSLog(@"NOW IN VIEW WILL APPEAR");
    for(Contact *cn in contactsToLayNow)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", cn.fName);
    }
    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];

    [quickDialTableView reloadData]; //MOREOVER EXCEPTION HERE IS THROWN 
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];


}
```

Comment: Does your NSLog works? Where and how is `quickDialTableView` declared? If an exception is thrown it might be because it's not accessible anymore.

Comment: What is the exception? Shouldn't the call to super be done at the beginning of your viewWillAppear method?

Comment: yes, it is declared, yes, NSLog displays the data expected. It's not even an exception, it's a crash with no exception log to console

Comment: put ur  [super viewWillAppear:YES]; as first line

Comment: No exception, but still nothing updated

Answer (score 0):

Move your `[super viewWillAppear:animated];` to first line of `viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to retain contactsToLayNow  - I guess it's being autoreleased sometime during your tableViews's drawing :)

```
contactsToLayNow = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fPath()] retain];
```

PS It's not required but you *should* put your call to super at the top of this method ;)